# Cannot close ghost projects in excel vba

Tags: excel, project, ghost-blog

I use Excel 2003 to get real-time data from stock market (500+ stocks, 12 data points each). The primary App (18,00 lines of code) also calculated trends, and predicts (tries) to indicate the best trade.

3 times a day I need to download additional information and export it to database (Open Price, Spread, and Closing values)

I do it by opening secondary Excel file **in the same instance** (opening in a separate instance will cost me additional $250 a month).

The problem is that though the secondary workbooks are closed, the "ghost" projects stay in the main app. As a result I get "out of memory" errors. Since I use the same secondary for both OpenPrice and ClosingValues, I actually end up with two "ghost" projects, both named "DailyValues"

I have tried closing the secondary workbook from inside it:

ThisWorkbook.Close

and from the calling App:

```
DoEvents
If IsWorkbookOpen(pstrFileName) = False Then
  Workbooks.Open (pstrFilePath & pstrFileName)
End If
Call ReadText("Saving Spread")
'Application.Run (pstrFileName & "!ExportSpreadAndClose")
Application.Run (pstrFileName & "!UpdateAndExport")
strExportTime = "Spread Exported at " & Format(Now(), "HH:mm")
lngSpreadCount = Workbooks(pstrFileName).Worksheets("SettingsSP").Range("SpreadCount").Value
If lngSpreadCount > 0 Then
 Call ReadText(Format(lngSpreadCount, "#,##0") & strExportTime)
 Debug.Print Format(lngSpreadCount, "#,##0") & strExportTime
Else
 Call ReadText("Error Exporting Spread")
 Debug.Print "Error Exporting Spread"
End If

If pbolCloseSpread = True Then
 If IsWorkbookOpen(pstrFileName) = True Then
    Workbooks(pstrFileName).Saved = True
    Workbooks(pstrFileName).Close
  End If
End If
```

Neither one helps.

There are no shared global variables, but I do read return value from export in the secondary app from primary.

Cold it be connected to database export? The primary app exports data to database (500+rows, 12+ columns) once every minute, with no ill effects.

In Excel 2010 I do not get memory errors, but the "ghost" projects remain. Excel 2010 is almost twice slower than 2003 - on the same machine (i7, 6 cores, 48Gb Memory, Server 2008 R2).

Please Advise

P.S. I've been working with Excel since 1992.

Comment: In 2007 Excel radically changed the system to XML. If your code runs slower on 2010 than 2003 it' because of adaptations being made to it on the fly. 18,00 lines (with or without an extra 0 :-)) are surely daunting but you may find guidance for what to look for easier than how to get rid of the ghost files.

Comment: It's ghost projects, not got files.

XML applies to storage method, not to pseudo-code. The actual .xlsm file is in reality a collection of zipped XML, .emf and other files. When open, it grows to 3-4 times the size of the file.

it's 18,000

Nowhere in Excel documentation, or on the web I was able to find a way to close a VBEProject. Apparently the method does not exist. Excel 2010 simply has better memory management (2Gb instead of 1Gb)

 No adaptations are made "on the fly". I open 2003 file in 2010, Excel highlights necessary, changes, I make them, and save 2010 .xlsm.